# WiX element not recognized

Tags: c#, wix

I need to use WiX manually with MSBuild, i'm trying to create test.wixproj. I'm just learning how to use WiX to create a deployer and i'm blocked. 
I would just deploy my img.png into a defined repertory.

I have this (test.wixproj) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" UpgradeCode="" Version="1.0.0.0" Language="1033" Name="My Application Name" Manufacturer="My Manufacturer Name">
        <Package InstallerVersion="300" Compressed="yes"/>
        <Media Id="1" Cabinet="myapplication.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />


        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" Name="Application test"/>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>


        <DirectoryRef Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY">
            <Component Id="myimg" Guid="">
                <File Id="myimg" Source="...\Desktop\img.png" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
            </Component>

        </DirectoryRef>


        <Feature Id="MainApplication" Title="Main Application" Level="1">
            <ComponentRef Id="myimg.png" />
        </Feature>
    </Product>
</Wix>
```

And when i run "MSBuild test.wixproj", i have this error :

> test.wixproj<2.1>: error MSB4068: The item "Wix" is not recognized or is not supported in this
>   context.

I'm lost, can you help me ? I have difficulty to understanding how this works.

**EDIT1** : I'm trying with .wixproj and .wxs and now i have an other problem.

```
The project was not found
```

I copied this example [your link](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/authoring_first_msbuild_project.html)

**EDIT2** : i think it's this line that is the source of problem.

```
<Import Project ="$(WixTargetsPath)" />
```

Comment: That's a ".wxs" file renamed to a ".wixproj" file. You need to create a proper ".wixproj" file as described [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/authoring_first_msbuild_project.html). Or use the VS plugin to add one to a VS project.

Comment: Oh yes, i'm stupid. I will try it with .wxs and .wixproj

Comment: I have a problem with example described in your link.

Comment: Well did you change the line `<Compile Include="Product.wxs" />` to include your actual ".wxs" file?

Comment: yes i changed with my test.wxs

Comment: "MSB4019: project imported "C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\WiX\v[[Version.M
ajor]].x\Wix.targets" was not found. " Make sure that path of <import> declaration are correct

Answer (score 1):

A ComponentRef should reference a Component by Id. You are using myimg.png as your ComponentRef Id, when there is no Component with that Id. Try changing the ComponentRef Id to "myimg".

`<ComponentRef Id="myimg" />`

Oh and as a side note, you should remove the GUIDs from your code if you're going to post it online.